# The server tag is not well formed on checkbox and itemtemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I am getting the error "The server tag is not well formed."

on the checkbox in this part of my code

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <table style="table-layout:fixed;" border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <td class="ListItem" style="padding-left:0px">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkbox" runat="server" Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,"Attributes['checked']") %>' ></asp:CheckBox>
      </td>
   </table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I guess this is due to the double quote inside the quote that contains single quotes... I tryed a lot of things like replace the single quote in the array by double quotes or even by trying to access to the attribute by an index, protecting the quotes... no sucess

I've seen a lot of threads about this error, but none helped. 
Any idea on what is wrong in there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [using inline syntax](http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/archive/2010/10/06/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags.aspx)

Change

```
  Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,"Attributes['checked']") %>'
```

to

```
  Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,"YourBoolPropName") %>'
```